# Dynamic creation of rich:treeNodesAdaptor from bean in jsf1.2

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces, jsf-1.2

```
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%" columnClasses="col1,col2">
                <rich:tree style="font-size:12px; width: 300px;" id="treeExample"
                    nodeSelectListener="#{treeComponentTest.actionEventOnRecursiveAdapter}"
                    ajaxSubmitSelection="true" ajaxSingle="true" switchType="ajax"
                    var="item" reRender="treeExample">
                    <rich:treeNodesAdaptor nodes="#{treeComponentTest.nodes}">
                        <rich:treeNode
                            changeExpandListener="#{treeComponentTest.actionEventOnRecursiveAdapter}" />
                    </rich:treeNodesAdaptor>
                </rich:tree>
            </h:panelGrid>
```

my concern is i want to generate the treeNodeAdapter every time from db as a child of a node of another adapter,kindly help how to write the bean

Comment: and event is not getting triggered either way, reason to use treenodeadapter is i have to keep track of folder id's as there can be many with same name

Comment: atleast i need id for list or id for each node i add to be stored as folder id which comes from db, so in this case i can add node by node as a child node, problem is interesting pls contact me any help is appreciated @gaddechaitu2323@gmail.com